Kenmore washing machine 600 series. Smell coming from water standing in drum
We got a used Kenmore washing machine when our old one suddenly quit working. Ever since, we have had a smell coming from the inside of washer. I have used bleach baking soda, washing machine cleaners but I believe there is standing water under the drum that may be from backflow in drain hoses. This is the first washer we have had that the hoses come from the bottom of the machine so it is the only thing I can think of different. I read this on another thread as a solution to fix this problem.

Even Better
Put a check valve on the back of the washer between the washer's outlet and the existing hose. This will allow the washer's pump to force water out of the tub, up hill and into the drain. When the pump kicks off, the valve will seal the drain pipe preventing the water from flowing down hill and back into the tub

I can not seem to find a specific check valve for this purpose. Any clues or part suggestions?

Have the check valves you've found specifically indicated that they're not for use in a washing machine installation? I can't imagine how one might be specially designed for a washer vs any other installation. So long as the connections fit/can be adapted and are water tight, what difference would it make?

It was more so that the ones 8 was finding said specifically sewer.or dish washer etc. yet I couldn't find one for washing machine. I didn't think it would make a difference but was just confused as to why it wouldn't be listed.

Is the "new" machine a front-loader?

Is this new machine intended to be mounted up high, off the floor, therefore giving the drain a downward slope not a hill to climb ?

You can use a standard check valve to solve your washing machine's backflow issue, as long as the connections fit and are watertight. It doesn't need to be labeled specifically for washing machines. Just ensure it prevents backflow effectively.

A washing machine!'s output hose should be hooked into a vertical pipe with an air gap, which serves as a vacuum break and prevents syphoning back from the drain. If yours is too tightly sealed to its drain, fixing that should probably be your first step.
